# How can I view the color contrast checker in chrome for windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I open the dev tools, inspect an element, and click on the little color picker box for a CSS property that has a color, there should be two lines on the color gradient plane and a section that tells me if the color contrast is AA or AAA compliant, but there isn't.

Is there a setting somewhere to turn this on? Is this a known bug?
Everything I read online says that it should just be there. I've also seen the contrast checker area before on my machine. Maybe it was on a previous version.

I'm running Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.
I have all browser extensions turned off, and I've restarted chrome.

Relevant threads from the chromium dev team:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=461320
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514674
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=879856

It looks like it may have been removed because of buggy performance, but I can't find anything definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they opted to put the color contrast score somewhere else in Chrome 84.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools#a11y

If you turn on the inspect cursor (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C`), then hover over an element, it will show you a few accessibility checks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are disabling  **"[Accessibility DevTools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/accessibility-developer-t/fpkknkljclfencbdbgkenhalefipecmb)"** by turning off all extensions. You should have that extension to have color contrast checking feature according to [this help](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/accessible-styles#color_and_contrast) from Google developers.

Comment: That extension looks like it would do similar things, but the color contrast feature that I'm looking for is built in which is most likely why that extension is deprecated now.